# how to build custom docker image from another docker image?

Tags: node.js, docker

I'm trying to dockerize my nodejs app that use `dimfacion/curaengine` image
I just want to build a single image for both but it gives me error when I run the image

this is my index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const { exec } = require('child_process');
const multer = require('multer');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;


const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: 'uploads/',
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
 
    const originalFilename = file.originalname;
    cb(null, originalFilename);
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage });

app.post('/slice', upload.single('stlFile'), (req, res) => {
  
  let stlFile = req.file.path;
  stlFile = stlFile.replace(/\\/g, '/');

  
  const command = `docker run -v ${__dirname}/uploads:/uploads dimfacion/curaengine slice -v -j /usr/src/Cura/resources/definitions/fdmprinter.def.json -l /uploads/${req.file.filename} 2>&1`;

  exec(command, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error(`Error: ${error.message}`);
      return res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
    }

    

    return res.send(stdout)
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App running on port ${port}`);
});
```

and this is what I used to create docker image

```
FROM node:14 AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM dimfacion/curaengine
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /app .
WORKDIR /app
CMD [ "node", "index.js" ]
```

but when I run this image I get this error

```
[ERROR] Unknown command: node
[ERROR] Command called:
[ERROR] /usr/src/CuraEngine/build/CuraEngine [ERROR] node [ERROR] index.js [ERROR]
```

Comment: You must install node on `dimfacion/curaengine`

Comment: i tried this 
```RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.17.3 | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
```
but im getting error  => ERROR [3/4] RUN apt-get install -y nodejs                                                                                                           0.6s
------
 > [3/4] RUN apt-get install -y nodejs:
#0 0.543 /bin/sh: apt-get: not found
------

Comment: i installed nodejs inside that image and index.js is running but cant execute docker commands inside it im getting this error 
```
docker run -p 3000:3000 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -it api2
App running on port 3000
Error: Command failed: docker ps
/bin/sh: docker: not found
```

Comment: also now im trying to run curaengine from nodejs inside dimfacion/curaengine image without calling docker command but it's not working

Comment: `Command failed: docker ps /bin/sh: docker: not found` you must install docker on the image.